# Flashdevelop for webgl with haxe & stdjs

Tags: javascript, webgl, flashdevelop, haxe

I am currently trying to get an instance of the WebGL context in HaxeJS using FlashDevelop. I would like to use the stdjs library.

I have imported the dependencies using haxelib with:

> haxelib git xirsys_stdjs https://github.com/xirsys/stdjs.git haxelib

I tested its availability with:

> haxelib list

I then added it to the library section in FlashDevelop - see pic

[image]

**I have included the the library in the classpaths (I really don't know if I should, but without it, compile won't even take place) - See pic **

[image]

I've then taken the WebGL specific code from the following github repo:
https://github.com/mikecann/WebGLTerrainicles/blob/master/src/Main.hx

When I try to compile the project, it opens up my browser as expected, however, in the console there is an issue as there are missing libraries:

[image]

Obviously I'm missing something here (perhaps in the import process?) - I've looked but can't find much information on getting WebGL working for Haxe with the stdjs externs etc using FlashDevelop and any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a problem with xirsys_stdjs lib.

The reference project you link to is using only one file called Html5Dom.hx (originally from Jeash project) to define the HTML5/webgl API. You don't need xirsys_stdjs if you reuse this file.

While you're at it, mikecann's project seems to include a lot of basic classes to get started writing webgl in haxe.

Comment: Yes, it is perhaps affecting code that is generated from HaXe?! I revisited mikecanns projects and I'll definitely try to get something out of his set of scripts but thanks for taking the time to take a look.